# Deserialize JSon using Newtonsoft in VB.net Collection of Data

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization, json.net

I have been struggling to try and deserialize this json that I have gotten from scraping Instagram. I have looked around to see how to do it but everything is in c# and converters can miss things. My code looks right to me but obviously, there is an error.

This is the type of JSON I want to parse, I want to be able to get a list of usernames and there ids, now coming to think about it, it will probably be better if I made it a dictionary? Anyway here is the json test data:

```
{  
"data":{  
  "user":{  
     "edge_follow":{  
        "count":1,
        "page_info":{  
           "has_next_page":false,
           "end_cursor":"AQAVc2MTmWj_GJRRdTbljsZIVf9JPlCXFzZhx2Io0bOJlq_qU-Oxu1Eu9u1HTB64CK8"
        },
        "edges":[  
           {  
              "node":{  
                 "id":"241164259",
                 "username":"cherylofficial",
                 "full_name":"Cheryl",
                 "profile_pic_url":"https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/15624120_1236093059810653_247544301280559104_a.jpg",
                 "is_verified":true,
                 "followed_by_viewer":false,
                 "requested_by_viewer":false
              }
           }
        ]
     }
  }
},
"status":"ok"
}
```

Classes:

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property data As Data
    Public Property status As String
End Class

Public Class Data
    Public Property user As User
End Class

Public Class User
    Public Property edge_follow As Edge_Follow
End Class

Public Class Edge_Follow
    Public Property count As Integer
    Public Property page_info As Page_Info
    Public Property edges() As Edge
End Class

Public Class Page_Info
    Public Property has_next_page As Boolean
    Public Property end_cursor As String
End Class

Public Class Edge
    Public Property node As Node
End Class

Public Class Node
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property username As String
    Public Property full_name As String
    Public Property profile_pic_url As String
    Public Property is_verified As Boolean
    Public Property followed_by_viewer As Boolean
    Public Property requested_by_viewer As Boolean
End Class
```

This is the code I am using to get the first id in the list:

```
Dim root As List(Of RootObject) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of RootObject))(followingJson)
            Dim id As Integer = root(0).data.user.edge_follow.edges(0).node.id
```

This is the error I get:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Instagram_Login.RootObject]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>
> Path 'data', line 1, position 8.'

Any help in solving this issue is appreciated, it's just that there aren't many examples of newtonsoft in action using VB.

Comment: Changed, sorry my bad.

Comment: That JSON is invalid so it hard to tell if the classes are correct or the code

Comment: Can you explain to me how the JSON is invalid? because that might be the issue?

Comment: Thats not the issue; you'd get a different error.  Paste the real json to the clipboard and use **Edit Menu** > **Paste Special** > **Paste JSON as Classes** to create classes that match, though a few fixups may be needed.  You can use jsonlint,com to validate the json.  Looks like you edited it to shorten or mask data

Comment: Ok so I checked the JSON  and it is valid, I also did the special paste in order to get the classes, but I still get the same error as before? I believe its something to do with the array or something?

Comment: But the JSON posted is **not** valid.  We cant tell what you what you did wrong without the valid data.  Yes it has to do with an array.  The User Property is probably supposed to be a collection but I am guessing

Comment: Even though the JSON is invalid (missing closing bracket `]` around line 21 plus several trailing commas; upload to https://jsonlint.com/ for details) the error message is self-explanatory.  You are trying to deserialize to a `List(Of RootObject)` but the root JSON container is an *object* -- a set of comma-separated key/value pairs surrounded by `{` and `}` -- and not an *array*.  Therefore you must deserialize to a `RootObject` -- i.e. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(followingJson)`.

Comment: I changed the classes and JSON example to an actual account. Also, your help was appreciated, but I want to get all of the nodes information, for example, there could be 300 nodes rather than just 1. Therefore, I must need to use some sort of array to store all the different data?

Comment: The container object (RootObject) is just an object not a collection.  There can/will be collections *inside it* but that json shows just one user, one edge one data.  Json with more than one user etc will generate different classes to accommodate them

Comment: I have this code:
Dim root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(followingJson) 
but how can I make it a collection then? Sorry, I do not fully understand what you are trying to say. This still gives me the error, because there is a collection of nodes and I am only accounting for 1 node - im assuming anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find some code which helped me!

Here it is:

```
Public Module JsonHelper
Public Function FromClass(Of T)(data As T, Optional isEmptyToNull As Boolean = False, Optional jsonSettings As JsonSerializerSettings = Nothing) As String
    Dim response As String = String.Empty
    If Not EqualityComparer(Of T).Default.Equals(data, Nothing) Then
        response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, jsonSettings)
    End If
    Return If(isEmptyToNull, (If(response = "{}", "null", response)), response)
End Function

Public Function ToClass(Of T)(data As String, Optional jsonSettings As JsonSerializerSettings = Nothing) As T
    Dim response = Nothing
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(data) Then
        response = If(jsonSettings Is Nothing, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of T)(data), JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of T)(data, jsonSettings))
    End If
    Return response
End Function
End Module
```

Then I used this to get all the ids

```
Dim response = JsonHelper.ToClass(Of Rootobject)(followingJson)
            Dim count As Integer = response.data.user.edge_follow.count
            For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
                Dim id = response.data.user.edge_follow.edges(i).node.id
                Console.WriteLine(id.ToString)
            Next
```